# Energy of a Bose-Einstein condensate (BEC) in a rotating ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I was looking at a Bose-Einstein condensate rotating in a ring. Now the energy of the BEC as a function of the angular frequency $\Omega$ is parabolic depending upon the eigenvalue of the angular momentum operator($L_z$) taken w.r.t the origin at the center of the ring as shown in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.2958v2.pdf. Now I do not understand this result at all.
The energy functional of a rotating BEC in two dimensions according to mean-field can be written as,
\begin{align}
E[\psi,\psi^*]&=E^\prime[\psi,\psi^*]-L_z.\Omega\\
&=\int [-\psi^*\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi-\Omega \psi^*L_z \psi +\frac{g}{2}|\psi|^4 +V|\psi|^2 ]dr \\
\end{align}
Both the contact interactions($g$) and external trapping potential $V$ should not change with $\Omega$. Writing down the kinetic energy and $L_z$ in terms of polar coordinates we get,
\begin{align}
E[\psi,\psi^*]&=\int [-\psi^*\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\{\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial r^2 }+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}\}\psi-\Omega \psi^*\{ i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\} \psi + ... ]dr \\
&=\int [-\psi^*\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial r^2 }+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right\}\psi+\psi^*\frac{\hbar^2}{2m r^2}\left\{i\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}+ \frac{\Omega}{\Omega_c}\right\}^2\psi-\frac{1}{2}m \Omega^2 r^2 |\psi|^2 + ... ]dr
\end{align}
where $\Omega_c=\hbar/mr^2$. Now the ring current solutions of the order parameter can we written as,
\begin{align}
\psi=\sqrt{\rho(r)}e^{il\phi}
\end{align}
where $l$ is the eigenvalue of $L_z$. Now if I put in the order parameter corresponding to  $l=0$ int the energy functional, I get no terms with $\Omega$ since all terms cancel out. This is more evident in the first line of the energy functional where the only term containing $\Omega$ i.e. $L_z \phi =0$. I must be missing something since this is a well-known result. Any help will be appreciated. Apologies in advance for any typos.